# Get rid of extra bullets for nested uls

Tags: html, list, html-lists

In `ul`s the only valid elements are `li`s. To put another `ul` inside a `ul` I have to wrap it in an `li` like so:

Illegal:

```
<ul>
  <li>first outer item</li>
  <ul>
    <li>inner item 1</li>
    <li>inner item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <li>second outer item</li>
</ul>
```

Legal:

```
<ul>
  <li>First outer item</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>inner item 1</li>
      <li>inner item 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Second outer item</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the second in chrome (haven't tested for other browsers) renders a bullet before the deeper bullet as below (two bullets before `inner item 1`. )

- First outer item
- - inner item 1
  - inner item 2
- Second outer item

Am I nesting it wrong? Should I fix this through CSS? (if so, a note how would be appreciated)

Comment: the nested ul is a subitem of the one before .. so take the nested ul to the "First outer item"-li tag ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the nested items are related to the previous item. The sublist should go into that item and not into an item of its own.

```
<ul>
  <li>First outer item <!-- No </li> -->
  <!-- No <li> -->
    <ul>
      <li>inner item 1</li>
      <li>inner item 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li> <!-- </li> for First outer item AND the list of inner items associated with it -->
  <li>Second outer item</li>
</ul>
```